# Vue 3 equivalent of Vue.extend().$mount()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

We have a semi large app (approx 200 .vue files) that is written in Vue 2. We are in the process of trying to migrate to Vue 3 but have run into a big problem. We have several (100+) components that get shown as 'popups' using Vuetify's v-dialog.

This is how we currently show / mount them: (from: [How to programmatically launch a Vuetify Dialog and wait for the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026220/how-to-programmatically-launch-a-vuetify-dialog-and-wait-for-the-response))

```
let componentInstance = Vue.extend(MYCOMPONENT)
 var oComponent = new componentInstance({ 
                propsData: oProps
            }).$mount();

            // now add it to the DOM
            var oEl = document.getElementById('app').appendChild(oComponent.$el);

var oLuanchBtn = document.getElementById(domID);
            if (oLuanchBtn){
                oLuanchBtn.style.display = 'none';
                oLuanchBtn.click();
            }
            
            // Add a listener so we can get the value and return it
            oComponent.$watch('retval', function(newVal, oldVal){
                // this is triggered when they chose an option
                // Delete the component / element now that I'm done
                oEl.remove();
}
```

As we migrate to Vue 3, Most of these are still written using the options API and will SLOWLY get re-written (as we have time) to the composition API. However, we still need the app to run and Vue 3 got rid of `extend().$mount()`. I've found a few articles that get me close using `createVNode() & render()` but they don't quite do it (see [Mount vue component - Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034882/mount-vue-component-vue-3) for example). Whenver I call the render() function I get

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Vuetify] Could not find defaults instance
> at useDefaults (defaults.ts:25:24)
> at setup (defineComponent.tsx:55:24)

I've also tried to get the 'appContext' like a few sites recommended by doing this in the `created()` (Yes, this is still in the options API)

```
this.vueContext = getCurrentInstance();
```

And then on the button click that launches the popup I do

```
let el = document.getElementById('app');
var propsData = { msg: mText, 
                    title: mTitle, 
                    btnCap1: mBtnCap1, 
                    btnCap2: mBtnCap2, 
                    btnCap3: mBtnCap3,
                    retval: 0,
                    mBoxBtnId: domID,
                }
let vNode = createVNode(MBOX, propsData);
vNode.appContext = this.vueContext.appContext; // take out this line and you get the '[Vuetify] Could not find defaults' error, keep it and you get a different error
var oEl = render(vNode, el);
```

But that just throws different errors. How do I not lose the $vuetify context / app context and still dynamically 'extend' / 'render' a component like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to thank Moritz Ringler as I couldn't have figured this out without his answer. Posting this as a separate answer in case anyone comes across this thread as this shows the 'migration' if you will. Here's the final working code and the several things I had to tweak from Vue 2 to Vue 3

This is all in a promise so I can await for the dialog to close and resolve the retval (return value)

```
Vue 2 Code:
// NOTE: domID is a random string value that's a part of oProps so I can reference the v-dialog button once it's rendered
let componentInstance = Vue.extend(MYCOMPONENT)
var oComponent = new componentInstance({ 
    propsData: oProps
}).$mount();

// now add it to the DOM
var oEl = document.getElementById('app').appendChild(oComponent.$el);

var oLuanchBtn = document.getElementById(domID);
if (oLuanchBtn){
    oLuanchBtn.style.display = 'none';
    oLuanchBtn.click();
}
            
// Add a listener so we can get the value and return it
oComponent.$watch('retval', function(newVal, oldVal){
    // this is triggered when they chose an option
    // Delete the component / element now that I'm done
    oEl.remove();
    resolve(Number(newVal));
}
```

```
Vue 3 Code:
// At top of script section:
import { createVNode, render, watch } from 'vue';

// in method
let el = document.getElementById('app').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
let vNode = createVNode(MYCOMPONENT, oProps); // MyComponent imported above
vNode.appContext = this._.appContext; // magic sauce for the Vuetify issue. Thanks Moritz Ringler!

var oEl = render(vNode, el);
var oLuanchBtn = document.getElementById(domID);
oLuanchBtn.style.display = 'none';
oLuanchBtn.click();

// Add a listener so we can get the value and return it
// NOTE: watch is now imported from vue
watch(() => vNode.component.data.retval, function(newVal, oldVal){       
    // this is triggered when they chose an option
    // Delete the component / element now that I'm done
    //oEl.remove();
    render(null, el);
    resolve(Number(newVal));
})
```

Changes I had to make to my component that contained the v-dialog

```
Vue 2
<template v-slot:activator="{on}">
     <v-btn :id="mBoxBtnId" v-on="on"></v-btn>
</template>

props: [ 'retval' ]
```

```
Vue 3
<template v-slot:activator="{props}">
    <v-btn :id="mBoxBtnId" v-bind="props"></v-btn>
</template>

data: () => ({ retval: null })
```

Answer (score 1):

In Options API, you can get `appContext` from the `this._` property:

```
vNode.appContext = this._.appContext
```

You can also use `getCurrentInstance()`, but it will only give you the instance during the setup phase (i.e. inside `setup()` function). Later calls to it will return null.

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, createVNode, render } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const mbox = {
  template: `
<v-dialog max-width="290" persistent v-model="showMbox">
    <template v-slot:activator="{props}">
        <v-btn id="mbox_btn_launch" v-bind="props">
            Show Dialog
        </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>{{title}}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>{{msg}}</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn v-if="btnCap1" @click="btnClicked('1')">{{btnCap1}}</v-btn>
            <v-btn v-if="btnCap2" @click="btnClicked('2')">{{btnCap2}}</v-btn>
            <v-btn v-if="btnCap3" @click="btnClicked('3')">{{btnCap3}}</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
  `,
  name: 'mbox',
  data: () => ({
    showMbox: false
  }),
  props: [
    'msg',
    'title',
    'btnCap1',
    'btnCap2',
    'btnCap3',
    'retval',
  ],
  methods: {
    btnClicked: function(mBtnClicked) {
      mBtnClicked = Number(mBtnClicked);
      this.retval = mBtnClicked;
      this.showMbox = false;
    }
  }
}



const app = {
  methods: {
    showDialog(){
      const el = document.getElementById('dialogMount');
      const propsData = {
        msg: 'Dialog Message',
        title: 'Dialog Title', 
        btnCap1: 'Button Text', 
        retval: 0,
      }

      const vNode = createVNode(mbox, propsData);
      vNode.appContext = this._.appContext;
      const oEl = render(vNode, el);
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.v-application__wrap{
  min-height: unset!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn @click="showDialog">Mount Dialog</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
  
  <div id="dialogMount"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```